# php url check available

Tags: php, url

I want to check whether url is available from my database. I choose `fopen`, but I test 30 rows from my database, it will cost nearly 20 seconds. Is there any way, can make it more efficient? Thanks.

```
<?php
$start_t = microtime(true); 
//connect database and select query
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
//$url = 'http://www.google.com'; //not test from database, but a google.com, one url will cost 0.49 seconds.
$url = $row['url'];
$res = @fopen($url, "r "); 
if($res){
    echo $row['url'].' yes<br />';
}else{
    echo $row['url']. ' no<br />';
}   
}
$end_t = microtime(true);
$totaltime = $end_t-$start_t;
echo "<br />".$totaltime." s";
?>
```

Comment: If you want to check if the DNS is okay or the server is online you can use the snippet from Rakesh. For checking the availability of the content you can use curl (see karim79's answer) or get_headers() (see yes123's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `fsockopen` which is faster than `fopen`

```
<?php

$t = microtime(true);

$valid = @fsockopen("www.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

echo (microtime(true)-$t);

if (!$valid) {
   echo "Failure";
} else {
   echo "Success";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
0.0013298988342285
```

Comment: @Rakesh, suprised speed. but neither  
`http://www.google.com` nor `http://google.com` they all return `failure`?

Comment: @Yuli like @yes123 my mistake. Generally you should be using just the hostname, not the URL in the fsockopen call. You'll need to provide the uri, minus the host/port in the actual HTTP headers.

Comment: Great. I alse look the `php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php`, move `http head` . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using CURL with the CURLOPT_NOBODY option set, which uses the HTTP HEAD method and avoids downloading the entire page:

```
$ch = curl_init($row['url']);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// 400 means not found, 200 means found.
curl_close($ch);
```

From the CURLOPT_NOBODY [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> TRUE to exclude the body from the
>   output. Request method is then set to
>   HEAD. Changing this to FALSE does not
>   change it to GET.

Comment: Thanks. it will save 20% time. but not only `400` and `200` return, also see `302`, etc. not a easiler

Answer (score 1):

You can't speed things up like that.

With 30 rows I assume you are connecting to 30 different urls. 20 seconds is already a good time for that.

Also I suggest you to use `file_get_contents` to retrive HTML
**Or if you need** to know the header response use `get_headers();`

If you want to speed up the process just spawn more process. Each of them will fetch a `tot` urls.

### Addendum

Also don't forget about the great `Zend_HTTP_Client();` that is very good for such task

Comment: `file_get_contents` like `get_headers`, cost more, tried a `http://www.google.com`, cost `1+ seconds`.

Comment: never said it would cost less

Answer (score 1):

Try Bulk URL check, that is, in blocks of 10 or 20

Curl Multi Exec.

http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading

Use the CURL options for NOBODY and HEADER ONLY, so your response will be much faster.

Also dont forget to put TIMEOUT for curl, else one BAD url may take too much time.

i was doing 50 URL checks in 20 secs.

Hope that Helps.

Comment: Thanks for reccommend a new class, but it will cost 10 seconds.